# SSRS Pass Date Parameter in URL

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2016

I have been trying to figure this out for a while now and I cannot seems to get it to work. I am trying to pass 2 date parameters to an SSRS report. I am using SSRS 2016. The link that gets you to the report is
http://ServerName/Reports/report/SomeFolder/ReportName I have tried following the unanimously agreed upon approach of simply appending &StartDt=01/01/2020&EndDt=01/31/2020 and other combination and listed below.
http://ServerName/Reports/report/SomeFolder/ReportName&StartDt=01/01/2020&EndDt=01/31/2020 
http://ServerName/Reports/report/SomeFolder/ReportName&StartDt=01-01-2020&EndDt=01-31-2020 
http://ServerName/Reports/report/SomeFolder/ReportName&rs:Command=Render&StartDt=01/01/2020&EndDt=01/31/2020 
http://ServerName/Reports/report/SomeFolder/ReportName&rs:Command=Render&StartDt=01-01-2020&EndDt=01-31-2020 
In all cases I get the almost the same error, with the only difference being how I added the dates. `The path of the item '/SomeFolder/ReportName&StartDt=01-01-2020' is not valid. The full path must be less than 260 characters long; other restrictions apply. If the report server is in native mode, the path must start with slash. (rsInvalidItemPath)` I have confirmed the parameters match StartDt and EndDt appear exactly that way in my report, just for SAG I even made the prompts match and they are Non null able Date/Time fields. None of available values or default values. If nothing is selected it has the calendar icon to pick a date and everything runs perfectly.

Comment: If it helps, it looks like when I use the 01/01/2020 format it tried to open subfolders that do not exists Somefolder>ReportName&StartDate=01>01>01>2020&EndDt=01>31>2020

Answer (score 1):

I actually think I saw something on this back in a .Net explanation but it came out to be the link below. As usual I never mark my answer as correct, but leave it for the next person.

http://ServerName/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2FFolderName%2FReportName&rc:showbackbutton=True&StartDt=01/01/2020&EndDt=01/31/2020